# DateTime, minutes since update?

Tags: c#

I have this DateTime object (update) which is set to DateTime.now, when i update my application.

I also have this timerTick event, called on every 5 seconds which should check how many minutes ago, update was.

I've tried with:

```
if ((DateTime.Now - Updated).Minutes > 0)
{
     updateTextBlock.Text = "updated " + ((DateTime.Now - Updated).Minutes).ToString() + " minutes ago";           
}
```

But it does not seem to work correctly. Isn't there a better way to do this?

/R

Comment: What is happening then? What do you _expect_ should happen?

Comment: looks okay to me though... are u sure the error is not somewhere different? And what do u mean by "it does not seem to work correctly"? Output?

Comment: I forgot to initialize Updated and when i changed to TotalMinutes it worked fine :) Thanks for your replys!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect you want [`TotalMinutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes.aspx) instead of `Minutes`. Otherwise you'll only ever get a value in the range -59 to 59.

You may also want to consider using `UtcNow` instead of `Now` - otherwise you could get odd effects due to time zone changes (either the user changing time zone, or the time zone changing its UTC offset, usually for daylight saving time.)

Answer (score 2):

You may find it easier to use an instance of [`System.Diagnostics.StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to keep track of how much time has elapsed since any particular starting point.

It can be more reliable and accurate than doing math on DateTime objects because it'll use the hardware's High Resolution Timer if one is available.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the correct type for addressing this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [`TotalMinutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes.aspx), not just [`Minutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.minutes.aspx). `TotalMinutes` will give you the total number of minutes in the interval, whereas `Minutes` only gives 0-59 (since you also have `Hours`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

One way I did something similar was using `TimeSpan`

I had two variables `timePassed` and `tickTime`

where I would set `tickTime` to be a 5 second `TimeSpan` and `timePassed` to be 0

```
TimeSpan tickTime = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,5); // 5 seconds
TimeSpan timePassed = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0); // 0 seconds
```

then in the handler for the tick event I would add `tickTime` to `timePassed`

```
timePassed = timePassed.Add(tickTime); \\ adds 5 seconds to the timePassed TimeSpan
```

Then you can use `timePassed` to get the time since update.
Hope this helps